# how rundeck connect to DB, does it use database connection pool?

Tags: rundeck, socket-timeout-exception

When I deploy my `Rundeck` and database on a different cloud `region`, sometime the following exception happens:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

But the app which I developed uses a database **connection pool**. The connection to the database never happens. How make `Rundeck` connect to the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable connection pool in Rundeck when you [set the RDB datasource](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/setting-up-an-rdb-datasource.html). Use the following setting in rundeck-config.properties:

dataSource.pooled = true

Hope it helps.